# Is this function tail recursive? Why does it fail for large lists?

Tags: prolog, tail-recursion

Is this function tail recursive?

```
incNth(0, [H1|T], [H2|T]) :-
  H2 is H1 + 1.
incNth(N, [H|T1], [H|T2]) :-
  N > 0, N2 is N - 1,
  incNth(N2, T1, T2).
```

For lists containing 500,000 elements , prolog says it run out of stack memory. How could I fix this ?

Edit: I am trying to use this function as a replacement for this function

```
insert(Ind,List,Val,NList) :-
    nth0(Ind,List,_,R),
    nth0(Ind,NList,Val,R)
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem. With SWI-Prolog, and a stack limit of 1GB I can make a list of 10 000 000 elements (that's 1e7), and successfully apply your predicate to it.

```
?- N = 10 000 000, length(L, N), maplist(=(0), L), incNth(N-1, L, R).
N = 10000000,
L = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0|...],
R = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0|...] ;
false.
```

This is 2 * 10 times longer list than yours.

If I try to make an even longer list, this is when I run out of stack space. Already this throws:

```
?- N = 50 000 000, length(L, N).
ERROR: Stack limit (1.0Gb) exceeded
ERROR:   Stack sizes: local: 1Kb, global: 4Kb, trail: 2Kb
ERROR:   Stack depth: 11, last-call: 18%, Choice points: 3
ERROR:   In:
ERROR:     [11] system:'$length'(_1226, 50000000)
ERROR:     [9] system:'<meta-call>'(<compound (:)/2>)
ERROR:     [8] '$tabling':'$wfs_call'(<compound (:)/2>, <compound (:)/2>)
ERROR:     [7] '$toplevel':toplevel_call(<compound (:)/2>, <compound (:)/2>)
ERROR:     [5] '$toplevel':'$execute_goal2'(<compound (:)/2>, [length:3])
ERROR: 
ERROR: Use the --stack_limit=size[KMG] command line option or
ERROR: ?- set_prolog_flag(stack_limit, 2_147_483_648). to double the limit.
```

Please show how you run the program and what error you see. Also tell us what Prolog implementation you are using.

Comment: I am using SWI-Prolog as you predicted , I am going to post extra code in a minute